# What is the easiest way to add a custom icon to an application using monodevelop?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mono .EXE assembly set explorer icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622143/mono-exe-assembly-set-explorer-icon)

I recently started a c# project with monodevelop as IDE (should run on both Windows and Linux) and I'd like to provide my own application icon for the .exe file, instead of the default one.

Any suggestion how this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the `Project Menu -> <project name> Options` and in the project option windows :

[image: project options]

Answer (score 3):

Right-click your project, Options, select the Build/General page and provide a Win32 icon.

Note that the icon will probably only show up on Windows, Linux uses a different way to display icons for executable files (can't help you here though).