# how to insert icon to mono application in c# in linux

Tags: c#, linux, icons

I know there are multiple similar questions but none of them answers what I want to know,

such as [What is the easiest way to add a custom icon to an application using monodevelop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491005/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-add-a-custom-icon-to-an-application-using-monodevelop)

I want to know if it's possible to insert icon to c# application in monodevelop so that I can see this icon in taskbar of gnome when the application run.

All answers suggest to fill in win32 icon - but that doesn't work for linux.

I would be happy with a shell script that set up an icon and application name for gnome and then start the application in mono. I believe it's possible because some python applications can do that

Answer (score -3):

Try with this

```
Project properties -> Application -> Icon and manifest, assuming Visual Studio 10
```

Comment: but visual studio doesn't work on linux. I will try running produced exe from windows on linux but I don't think it's going to work :/

Comment: Try to make run through your virtual box, it will defiantly make a work.