# Cannot set application icon for a GTK# application in Monodevelop 3.1.1

Tags: mono, icons, monodevelop, gtk#

I set the icon as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12491626/67824 but it still shows as a generic app icon (grey screen with green "exec" text) in the dock and in the ⌘+tab application switcher (both when I run it from MonoDevelop and when I run it using `mono foo.exe`). I know it can be done, because when I run a [mono-compliant version of LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/LINQPad092.zip) I'm seeing the LINQPad application icon.

Answer (score 0):

I also use the SetIconFromFile method in the main window's class.  Example below where my icon is copied to an Images folder at the root of my application:

```
this.SetIconFromFile(string.Format("{0}{1}Images{2}Logo.ico", 
   System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), 
   System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 
   System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work, still shows as a generic app icon. Perhaps there are certain requirements to the icon size - what are your icon's dimensions?